# Example of convergence in distribution but not in probability

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

While I was looking for an example of a sequence of random variables which converges in distribution, but doesn't converge in probability, I have read that it should be enough to consider a sequence of independent and identically distributed non-degenerate random variables. I don't understand why... Can someone explain (or correct if it isn't right)?
Thank you

Comment: They all have the same distribution (identically distributed) so there is convergence in distribution. But if they are not degenerate then there is no convergence in probability (independent).

Comment: @drhab Sorry for answering so late, let's take X and Y indep. and identically distributed and $X_n = X  \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. It's clear that there is convergence in distribution. If there is convergence in probability, then it must be $P(X=Y)=1$. I want to show that in this case there is $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(X=c)=P(Y=c)=1$. I think I'm able to do this if X and Y are discrete (suppose $P(X=c)<1  \forall c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $P(X=c)=(P(X=c))^2=0 \forall c$, absurd, where the last equality follows from indep.). Could you help me for the general case?

Comment: If $X,Y$ are independent with $P\left(X=Y\right)=1$ and $F$ denotes
their common CDF then$F\left(x\right)=P\left(X\leq x\right)=P\left(X\leq x\wedge Y\leq x\right)=P\left(X\leq x\right)P\left(Y\leq x\right)=F\left(x\right)^{2}$.
This implies that $F\left(x\right)\in\left\{ 0,1\right\} $ for each
$x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then the characteristics of $F$ as a CDF (right-continuous, non-decreasing, non-constant and taking values in $[0,1]$) tell us that $F=1_{[c,\infty)}$ for some constant $c$. This implies that
$P\left(X=c\right)=1$.

Answer (score 15):

Choose the probability space $([0,1],\mathscr{B},m)$. ($\mathscr{B}$ consists of all Borel sets of $[0,1]$, $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.)

Let $X_{2n}(\omega)=\omega$, $X_{2n-1}(\omega)=1-\omega$.

Show that $X_{2n}$ and $X_{2n-1}$ have the same distribution. (Uniform distribution.)

Show that $\{X_n\}$ does not converge in probability.

Comment: the most simple exam ever seen

Comment: Wow, I'm THAT stupid.

Comment: I don't really understand this. Can you unpack further?

Comment: @Learningstatsbyexample I've posted the proof in my answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4652815/481713

Comment: @paperskilltrees I've posted the proof in my answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4652815/481713

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example of a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n\geq1}$ defined on $\Omega$ which converges in distribution to $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ but does not converge in probability to $X$.

Consider the abstract space $\Omega=\{0,1\}$ and

\begin{cases}
X_n(0)=0\\
 X_n(1)=1\\
X(1)=0\\
 X(0)=1  
\end{cases}
all with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

Then we have
$$X_n\xrightarrow[]{\text{dist}}X$$
because $F_n=F$, where $F_n$ and $F$ are the distribution functions of $X_n$ and $X$ respectively.

However, $$X_n\xrightarrow[]{\text{prob}}X$$ does **not** hold since we have $|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|=1$, for $ \omega\in\Omega$. Thus
$$P(\omega \in \Omega: |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|>\epsilon)\not\to 0.$$

Comment: So just pick 2 different random variables with the same distribution. Amazing I struggled so hard when the answer is so simple, I keep getting this idea that any type of convergence must mean the $X_n$ must look more and more similar to $X$. My iq must be sub 50.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_0 = \text{Uniform}[0,1]$,

$X_{2n} = X_0$, $X_{2n+1} = 1 - X_0$

$X_n$ has the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, so they converge in distribution.

Suppose $X_n$ converges in probability to some random variable $X$, then
\begin{align}
P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) + P(|X_{n+1} - X| > \epsilon) &\ge P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon \text{ or } |X_{n+1} - X| > \epsilon)\\
&= P(\max(|X_n - X|, |X_{n+1} - X|) > \epsilon)\\
&= P(\max(|X_n - X|, |1 - X_{n} - X|) > \epsilon)\\
&\ge P(\max(|X_n - X|, |1 - X_{n} - X|) > \epsilon \text{ and } |X-\frac{1}{2}| > \frac{1}{4})
\end{align}

Given that $|X - \frac{1}{2}| > \frac{1}{4}$, it's impossible for both $X_n$ and $1 - X_n$ to be within $\epsilon$ of $X$. Therefore $P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) + P(|X_{n+1} - X| > \epsilon)$ cannot possibly go to zero.

Comment: This is an addendum to Eclipse Sun's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1348195) showing that $(X_n)$ does not converge in probability (Eclipse Sun skipped the details).